# Beautifulsoup Search keyword in attrs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

After getting the source code, I have

```
[<div amy="sister" tommy="brother" julie="link1">E11</div>]
[<div amy="sister" tommy="brother" julie="link2_cat">E12</div>]
[<div amy="sister" tommy="brother" julie="link3_cat">E13</div>]
```

I want to extract the ones contain "_cat" in julie. How can I do it with find_all(attr)?

I try

```
soup.find_all('div',{"julie":re.compile("_cat")})
```

But doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4

html = '''<div amy="sister" tommy="brother" julie="link1">E11</div>
<div amy="sister" tommy="brother" julie="link2_cat">E12</div>
<div amy="sister" tommy="brother" julie="link3_cat">E13</div>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

soup.find_all('div',{"julie":re.compile("_cat")})
```

out:

```
[<div amy="sister" julie="link2_cat" tommy="brother">E12</div>,
 <div amy="sister" julie="link3_cat" tommy="brother">E13</div>]
```

you should use `find_all()` in `soup` object, not in a list of tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to get to the `julie` tag attribute values, [treat each matched tag as a dictionary](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
In [5]: [tag["julie"] for tag in soup.find_all('div',{"julie":re.compile("_cat")})]
Out[5]: ['link2_cat', 'link3_cat']
```

There is also a more concise way to match the desired elements - [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
In [6]: [tag["julie"] for tag in soup.select('div[julie$=_cat]')]
Out[6]: ['link2_cat', 'link3_cat']
```

`$=` selector means "ends with".